# Combination of StringEncryption with ClassesEncryption

Tags: android, dexguard

Does make sense to encrypt Strings the class A and then encrypt the whole class?

```
-encryptstrings ...
-encryptclasses ...
```

Or does it just add an unnecessary overhead and I'll be fine with the string encryption only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying both techniques increases the level of obfuscation, so it indeed makes sense.